# invalid input syntax for integer: "null"

Tags: postgresql, casting, null, syntax-error, invalidation

```
SELECT GROUP_ID FROM KM_MAST_GROUP WHERE  (OWNER=4629 or CREATED_BY::int=4629)
```

owner is int and created_by is varchar
I am getting error like **invalid input syntax for integer: "null"** i am not getting how to do the type casting. Anyone help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following query:

```
select *
from KM_MAST_GROUP 
where CREATED_BY !~ '[0-9]+';
```

It will give you all rows, where `CREATED_BY` is not a number. Fix such rows, and your query will work.

Other way is to use strings instead of integers.

```
SELECT GROUP_ID 
FROM KM_MAST_GROUP 
WHERE CREATED_BY = '4629';
```